# Change onarcade script url

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a problem with Change url Script onarcade .

the code is

> $categoryurl = $siteurl."/category/".$categoryId."/".$categoryId;

and in the .htaccess file

> RewriteRule ^category/([0-9]+)/([_A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ browse.php?c=$1 [L]

the url like this

http://games.myarabvideos.com/category/1/1

I want the url become

http://games.myarabvideos.com/categoryNAME/1/1

$categoryNAME Variable on php code

example:

$categoryNAME=games;

i try this

> $categoryurl = $siteurl."/category/".$categoryNAME."/".$categoryId;

**but my problem in .htaccess file What Changes ??**

Answer (score 0):

The rewriterule you wrote down does **not** seem to be related to you desired redirect.

For what you need (and what I can understand), just replace:

$categoryurl = $siteurl."/category/".$categoryId."/".$categoryId;

with:

$categoryurl = $siteurl."/category/".$categoryNAME."/".$categoryId;

and that's all, in my opinion. Now you have to redirect all old ID urls to the new ones, one by one with **single** 301 redirect (no regex) i.e:

```
redirect 301 /category/1/1 http://yoursite.com/category/nameof1
redirect 301 /category/2/2 http://yoursite.com/category/nameof2
redirect 301 /category/3/3 http://yoursite.com/category/nameof3
...
```

and so on. Hope this helps ;-)